# Removing duplicate rows by adding column value

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
ID   colA  ColB   ColuC
1     a      b      4
1     a      b     -4
1     a      b      5
4     c      b      2
```

Wants to return as below table

```
ID   colA  ColB   ColuC
1    a      b      5
4    c      b      2
```

Comment: Your sample data has same colA and colB for an ID. Always like that?

Comment: Removing duplicate rows isn't the same as adding the last value. What if instead of 4 and -4 for ID 1 you had 2, 2 and -4? The duplicates would be both 2s while the sum would be 0.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `SUM` with `group by`

```
SELECT ID,colA,ColB,SUM(ColuC) ColuC
FROM T
GROUP BY ID,colA,ColB
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `SUM()`:

```
SELECT ID, colA, colB, sum(coluC)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY ID, colA, colB;
```

Comment: How's that going to help? What happens when there are the following 3 values for column C for the same group: `1`, `2`, `-3` ? The sum will be 0 and there are 3 different values. Now, what if the 3 values are `1`, `1` and `-2` ?

Comment: The question is about *removing duplicates* by adding values. Your solution simply sums up column C. Perhaps, you can improve your solution a little bit by adding a `HAVING SUM(ColC) <> 0` to it. It would still not be accurate though since you return the sum for Column C instead of the non-duplicated value in Column C. Especially in the case `1`, `1`, `-2` .. The duplicate values `1` should be removed and `-2` be retained.

Comment: This solution gives the result set the OP is looking for. The answer is fine, but the question is a little sketchy.

Answer (score 0):

use aggregate function

```
select ID, min(colA),min(colB),max(coluC)
from t group by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use grouping by `abs()` function :

```
select *
  from tab
 where ColuC in
     (
        select abs(coluC)
          from tab 
        group by abs(coluC)
        having count(*)=1
      );
```

or without subquery use

```
with tab( ID, ColA, ColB, ColuC ) as
(
 select 1,'a','b',4 union all
 select 1,'a','b',-4 union all
 select 1,'a','b',5 union all
 select 4,'a','b',2   
)   
select ID, ColA, ColB, abs(coluC) as coluC
  from tab 
 group by ID, ColA, ColB, abs(coluC)
having count(*)=1;
```