# Removing duplicates from Excel rows by adding values of some columns

Tags: python, sql, excel, database, algorithm

I have an Excel file containing 500 rows containing product details and their quantities in different programs. All these 500 rows are duplicated products with different quantities. I would like to remove duplicates and add up quantities so instead of 5 rows having productID D1 I want to have one row only (quantities of 4 other rows is added to the remaining row)
[I am looking to create bottom table from top one]

[image]
I found similar problem on stackoverflow and people suggested uploading the data in the database and have sum(quantity1), sum(quantity2),...but I have 150 columns so I would not be able to write a query for that. ([Removing duplicate rows by adding column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53835645/removing-duplicate-rows-by-adding-column-value))

I am thinking of writing a python script but I am not sure how I can handle the duplicates.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Did you try pivoting ? For Price you can take MAX and for others SUM.

Comment: pivoting would not work as I have to drag 150 items into the columns, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy first 3 columns to another sheet or somewhere else. Use "Remove Duplicates". In order to find sum of quantites use a formula similar to this:

```
=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$500, $A$2:$A$500, $A2, $B$2:$B$500, $B2, $C$2:$C$500, $C2)
```

Then drag the formula to find other quantities.

Comment: Thanks for easy excel solution. It worked for me and I will try the other solutions later

Answer (score 1):

You can try "Pivot Table" in excel. Than summarize your data.

Ref: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

https://exceljet.net/things-to-know-about-excel-pivot-tables

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your image but assuming it's fairly standard layout:
If you can sort the data by productid you can use the built in functionality of Excel for this. Use Data, Subtotal - specify that on each change in ProductID you wish to Sum quantity. Then collapse the resultant table so only the totals are shown. Use Home, Find and Select,Goto Special, visible cells only. Then copy and past to a second sheet
You now have all the products totals.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
        "ProductsID": ["A1", "A1", "B1", "B1", "B1"], 
        "Category": ["MM", "MM", "NN", "NN", "NN"],
        "Price": [50, 50, 42, 42, 42],
        "Quantity1": [1, 8, 5, np.nan, 4],
        "Quantity2": [6, 3, np.nan, 2, 3]})

grouped = df.groupby(by=["ProductsID", "Category"])
agged = grouped.agg({"Price": "max", 
                "Quantity1": "sum", 
                "Quantity2":"sum"})

result = agged.reset_index()
```

The result:

```
  ProductsID Category  Quantity1  Quantity2  Price
0         A1       MM        9.0        9.0     50
1         B1       NN        9.0        5.0     42
```

Comment: Should I enter the data all manually for 150 columns and 500 rows in the df dataframe? and later in the aggregation repeat those 150 column names?

Comment: You can use `pandas.read_excel` to read in your file. Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html.